# Android: Not able to add Android Library to the Project

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I am using Eclipse to develop Android apps. I am importing one example to the Eclipse Workspace. But I am not able to run that project as it does not load the Android library to that project.

Please see this screen shot:

In SlidingDrawer there is Android 2.2 library is added but in SlidingDrawer_Original i am not able to load the android library.

[image]

I have cleaned the project and also built the workspace but still the problem is not solved.

if I open the Java file from the SlidingDrawer_Original then it seems like below image:

[image]

So What should I have to do to load the Android Library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it is Happen, But as i come to know, Eclipse always required its properties file. In Some Eclipse it is named as default.properties and in some eclipse it is as project.properties.

I have simply copy paste the default.Properties file and put it in to that project.
Then create the copy of that project in the same Workspace and remove the previous one project.

It solve my Issue. Hope it will also helpful to you.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 1):

Right click Project properties >Select Android > Select your target AVD

Comment: I am not able to select the targetAVD.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a file called .`classpath` , just check the Attribute of this file, It must be in read only mode, Change it to Archive Mode and the Clean the Project and set Proper Project Build and try again.